PCB inverter design
While prototyping a inverter or a power converter on bread boards we use separate power supply for microcontrollers and separate supply for gate triggering. But how to design a PCB for an inverter or power converter without using separate power supplies for microcontrollers and gate drivers... designing only by using input supply

What is your input voltage range? If it's higher than 5 V, it's unlikely you find a mcu that you can power directly from the input.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A fuller description of an example situation would help people to provide good answers. || Q1 Do you mean that the gate drivers are "floating" or at well above ground voltages? || Q2 Are you familiar with high side driver "diode pump" circuits || Q3 and ICs that incorporate these as part of the driver? || Q4 are you aware of DC Dc converters in this role?

See this web search


But how to design a PCB for an inverter or power converter without
using separate power supplies for microcontrollers and gate drivers...
designing only by using input supply

Use is made of isolated DC-to-DC converters that have very low barrier capacitance, a high dv/dt barrier immunity and, of course, a high barrier voltage withstand. Typically, the best devices are made by Recom and Murata.

As noted by the Community Bot - to get a good answer this question very probably needs improving. While an early answer MAY be adequate for the OP, it is very likely that there is not enough information in the question and that a degree of refinement is needed. If this happens this answer MAY become somewhat invalidated as the question is improved. An early answer to an improvable question is probably not as good as asking for clarification. || As Ranesh is a new contributor, some guidance and toleration is in order. Also, he may not use English as his primary language. (Not certain).
